# ORA-00911: invalid character using execute immediate

Tags: oracle

Below code am using to create the partititon dynamically. Am facing the error invalid chararcter error. While executing the message ouput i am not facing any error. Please help me to solve this issue.

```
create or replace package        shs_pk_dyn_par is
        procedure dynamic_proc ( p_table_name in varchar2,p_month_from in number,p_month_to in number,p_status out varchar2 , p_messgae out varchar2 );
end;

create or replace package body shs_pk_dyn_par is

procedure dynamic_proc ( p_table_name in varchar2,p_month_from in number,p_month_to in number,p_status out varchar2 , p_messgae out varchar2 ) is

v_sql           varchar2(4000);
v_month_from    number;
v_month_to      number;
v_append        number;
v_year          number;
v_p_year        number;
v_p_check       number;
begin

        p_status := 'S';
        p_messgae := 'Success';

        v_month_from := 0; v_month_to := 0;v_sql :=null;v_append:=null;v_year:=null;v_p_year:=null;
        v_p_check := null;

        v_month_from := substr(p_month_from,5,6 );
        v_month_to   := substr(p_month_to,5,6 );
        v_year       := substr(p_month_to,1,4 );
        ---v_sql := ' ALTER TABLE '||p_table_name||' ADD';

        for i in v_month_from..v_month_to
        loop

            if length(i) = 1
            then
                v_append := 0;
            else
                v_append := null;
            end if;
            v_p_year :=null;
            v_p_year := i+1;

            if length(v_p_year) = 1
            then
                v_p_check := v_year||trim(v_append)||v_p_year;
            else
                v_p_check := v_year||v_p_year;
            end if;
            dbms_output.put_line('v_p_check'||'='||v_p_check);
            if i=1 
            then
                v_sql := ' ALTER TABLE '||p_table_name||' ADD PARTITION P_'||v_year||trim(v_append)||i||' VALUES LESS THAN ('||v_p_check||')'||';';
            else
                v_sql := v_sql||chr(10)||' ALTER TABLE '||p_table_name||' ADD PARTITION P_'||v_year||trim(v_append)||i||' VALUES LESS THAN ('||v_p_check||')'||';';
            end if;

        end loop;
        dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
        begin
            execute immediate ( v_sql );
        exception when others
        then
            p_status := 'F';
            p_messgae := 'Failure'||sqlerrm||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace;
            return;
            dbms_output.put_line('exec'||sqlerrm||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
        end;    
        exception when others
        then
            p_status := 'F';
            p_messgae := 'Failure'||sqlerrm||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace;
            return;
            dbms_output.put_line('dynamic_proc'||sqlerrm||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace);
        end;

        end;



        For Execution
        -----------------------------------------
        declare
                p_status   varchar2(1);
                p_message  varchar2(4000);
        begin
                shs_pk_dyn_par.dynamic_proc('EMPLOYEES_PAR',201302,201311,p_status,p_message);
                dbms_output.put_line('p_status'||'='||p_status||'='||'p_messgae'||'='||p_message);
        end;
```

Comment: is it possible for you to just use a range partition? then the partitions will be created automatically for you.

Comment: hi Davek, While creating the table time itself partition added for a month . Later we need to add the partition for a whole year at the time need to add one by one. To avoid that i chose this way. Can u please help me on this

Comment: What is the output of your `dbms_output.put_line`?

Answer (score 1):

The semicolon is a statement separator; it is that that is the invalid character. You can only execute a single statement with `execute immediate`, you can't build up a series of SQL statements and execute them all in one go. So you'll need to remove the semicolon and move the `execute immediate` into the loop, remove the concatenation of the statements, and remove the final semicolon from each individual statement:

```
begin
    ...
    loop
        ...
        dbms_output.put_line('v_p_check'||'='||v_p_check);
        v_sql := ' ALTER TABLE '||p_table_name
            ||' ADD PARTITION P_'||v_year||trim(v_append)||i
            ||' VALUES LESS THAN ('||v_p_check||')';
        dbms_output.put_line(v_sql);
        execute immediate ( v_sql );
    end loop;
exception when others
then
    p_status := 'F';
    p_messgae := 'Failure'||sqlerrm||dbms_utility.format_error_backtrace;
    return;
end;
```

(line breaks added just to stop the code scrolling)

You'll need to look at your exception handler too; probably just have remove the version that was attached to that sub-block as I've done, as it seemed a bit pointless anyway, but you could still wrap each call in its own block if you really wanted to.

I don't think you really need any exception handlers at all - not sure why you wouldn't just let the caller handle the exception itself rather than having `out` parameters you have to set. Catching `others` is normally a bad idea. The code after the `return` is never going to be called, incidentally. But that's going a bit off-topic...